БД: производительность множественных запросов без выражений и единственного запроса с кучей выражений
Условная ситуация: нужно чанками обработать много записей -- добавить значение для одного поля.
Даже в пределах одного чанка очень много условий, большая часть их них по уникальным значениям (от динамически генерируемых 1000 условий)
Какой вариант производительнее:
UPDATE table SET column = 1 WHERE id in (1,2,3);
UPDATE table SET column = 2 WHERE id in (4,5,6);
UPDATE table SET column = 3 WHERE id in (7,8,9);

UPDATE table SET column = CASE
WHEN id in (1,2,3) THEN 1
WHEN id in (4,5,6) THEN 2
WHEN id in (7,8,9) THEN 3


Если обновляется не вся таблица, то вариант с where id in () видится более оптимальным. Если обновляется в итоге вся таблица, то примерно одинаково. должно быть Все зависит от объема таблицы и частоты использования. Условно, если таблица часто обновляется, то update всей таблицы приведет к блокировке всех записей... Проведите эксперимент и замерьте время обновления так и так.

Ну это бенчмаркать нужно. Думаю, будет ещё зависеть от того, есть ли индексы на колонки column и id. Если на column есть индекс, то это три раза надо будет индекс перестраивать в таблице. Возможно, если это всё в одной транзакции, БД как-то это оптимизирует, но не уверен. Ну и если на id вдруг нет индекса, то первый вариант - это опять же три полных прохода по таблице. Я не сильно разбираюсь в БД но кажется так. В лучшем случае разницы не будет, а в худшем вроде бы второй вариант оптимальнее во всех вариантах выглядит.

Второй выглядит быстрее. При изменениях одних страниц с данными сразу будут подготовлены новые страницы со всеми изменениями. В WAL будет писаться только одна копия таких страниц. Значит записей на диск меньше. НО пти оптимизатора не исповедимы, надо прогнать explain посмотреть планы выполнения запросов, сравнить скорости. И вот еще как вариант, почти как второй UPDATE table T SET column = N.column FROM (values(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (7, 3)) N(id, column) WHERE T.id=N.id  генерить из программы гораздо проще, вычислительной работы на Не исполнении ветвей case меньше.

если вы запрос сгенерируете на миллион in(...) значений то это тоже врядли отработает
